# "I want a cup of coffee" vs "I want a coffee"

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countability

As far as I'm concerned, the sentence "I want a cup of coffee" sounds natural, but what about "I want a coffee"? Is it correct?

I used Google search to find the number of times both of them are used. I'm in Peru, a Spanish speaking country.

- Searching *"I want a coffee" -traductor -traduccion -translation* shows 2,660,000 results.
- Searching *"I want a cup of coffee" -traductor -traduccion -translation* shows 2,850,000 results.

So it seems that both are used. Could anyone confirm if both are grammatically correct?

Comment: Please note that [Google's numbers are fake](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/397/191178).

Comment: This seems like it might be answered by [Is the counting nouns such as "a cup of" "a bottle of" virtually dead?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/93421/41273). (Note that coffee pretty much always comes in a cup.)

Comment: I want a coffee = usually,  you buy that. If you are at home, you would just say: I want some coffee or a cup of coffee.  But the meaning is the same as cup of coffee.

Comment: @Laurel that question was posted in 2010, data driven statistics may have changed a lot since then. I would like to see an updated assessment because I have grown to dislike and distrust Google's estimates (which appear to be inflated at the best of times) but I do not know what the hard cold facts are.

Answer (score 2):

when one says **coffee** it is often implied to mean **a cup of coffee**
(Particularly in places where coffee is usually served in cups.)

*To avoid ambiguity you can be precise by saying "a cup of coffee".*

Comment: It means 'a serving of coffee', whether they serve it in cups, mugs or whatever.